# WP foods restaurant and delivery network website

Tags: wordpress

I am going to start a wp food restaurants and delivery network. I am looking for a plugin or help how would that work? I want restaurants can register themselves in my website and sell foods from website and another i want a delivery guy dashboard for example i have 2 delivery guys they can check the orders and deliver foods from restaurants to customer's doorstep.. I am not sure how would that work if there is plugin available it would save my time and money..

Thank you

Comment: Distribution and logistics would be key words to plug into a search engine. This site is for programming questions.

Comment: lol i tried these keywords but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

This plugin did work for e-commerce platform with the help of WordPress you can create your food as products and sell everything you need. it will help you be related to the selling and receiving orders.